# DNN Sitemap broken, 404 error

Tags: dotnetnuke, sitemap, dotnetnuke-7

I have an issue with a DNN (DotNetNuke) 07.04.01 site that has no sitemap when I visit domain/sitemap.aspx. This may have been caused by somebody creating a page called sitemap which I have since removed but now the website is giving me a 404 response instead of a generated XML file. When I looked into the /Portals/0/ folder there was no sitemap folder or file.

The coreSitemapProvider is visible and enabled when I go to the search engine sitemap page of the website. I have tried disabling and enabling this then clearing the cache and restarting the application but this has had no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the cause of this issue. For some reason the website was missing a handler mapping for the sitemap. I added this back in through the web.config file as so:

```
<system.webServer>
   <handlers>
      <add name="SitemapHandler" path="Sitemap.aspx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Sitemap.SitemapHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode" />
   </handlers>
</system.webServer>
<system.web>
   <httpHandlers>
      <add path="Sitemap.aspx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Sitemap.SitemapHandler, DotNetNuke" />
   </httpHandlers>    
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you empty the recycle bin after deleting the page?